# How to figure out whether or not a particular mode is currently enabled using Emacs in Elisp?

Tags: emacs, mode

I want to write an Elisp script that will

- turn the `auto-save-visited-mode` on, if it is off, and
- do nothing if it is already turned on.

**How can I find out whether or not this mode is enabled at the moment in Elisp?**

**Update 1:** `M-x describe-mode` shows a list of all enabled minor modes.

[image: Screenshot showing minor mode list]

**Update 2:** According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511827/399457) you can display a list of all active minor modes using this code:

```
(defun which-active-modes ()
  "Give a message of which minor modes are enabled in the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((active-modes))
    (mapc (lambda (mode) (condition-case nil
                             (if (and (symbolp mode) (symbol-value mode))
                                 (add-to-list 'active-modes mode))
                           (error nil) ))
          minor-mode-list)
    (message "Active modes are %s" active-modes)))

(which-active-modes)
```

**Update 3:** Final version that seems to work:

```
(if auto-save-visited-mode
    (message "The mode is on")
    (message "The mode is off")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if it enabled by simply evaluating the variable `auto-save-visited-mode`, as discussed in its documentation, <kbd>C-h v</kbd>`auto-save-visited-mode`.

To enable it, just call `(auto-save-visited-mode 1)`. This will enable it or do nothing.

Edit:
`(auto-save-visited-mode 1)` by itself will probably accomplish what you want, but it does run the setup code / call the mode hooks again even if it was previously setup.  So, you *could* use `(unless auto-save-visited-mode (auto-save-visited-mode))` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

If the mode is on then the value of its mode variable is non-`nil`.  If it is off then the value is `nil`.